# Notation to address each tensor element

Tags: notation, tensors

I'm writing a piece with a lot of N-dimensional tensors $T \in \mathbb{R}^{n_1 \times n_2 \times \cdots}$. Most of the time the the actual shape, i.e. the values of $n_1$, $n_2$, and so on, are irrelevant and thus I don't want to carry them with me.

Consider for example the case that I want to state that every value of $T$ lies in the interval $[0, 1]$:

$T = [t_{i,j,\cdots}]_{n_1 \times n_2 \times \cdots}$ with $t_{i,j,\cdots} \in [0, 1]$

This is tedious if done multiple times without adding any information.

I'm looking for a notation that basically says "every element in this tensor".
Imagine this is denoted by a circle over the variable. The above could be denoted by:

$\overset{\circ}{T} \in [0, 1]$

---

1. Is there a short (preferably as short as my) notation that does what I described above and that I'm unaware of?
2. If not, have you suggestions how I could denote it? In the above example I used the circle as symbol, since it is commonly used within the [hadamard products or the analogous operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)), which are also applied elementwise.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with using greek letters? Like for example $T_{\mu_1\cdots \mu_p} \in [0,1]$. This is a notation I see a lot in books that prove tensor calculus related theorems.

Comment: Its more about the verbosity rather than the letters used. I'm looking for a short notation, since I have to do it multiple times throughout the document. I edited the question to reflect this better.

Comment: Then that notation I gave is what you are looking for.

Comment: Sorry, in that case I misunderstood you. Could you give me a source where such a notation is used?

Comment: Quite literally any book on tensor calculus will have that notation. But [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/gr-qc/9712019.pdf) is an explicit source, look at equation (1.51), (1.67), (1.68), (1.71), (1.79), (1.82), etc...

Comment: Thanks. Could you write this up as an answer in order for me to accept this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the notation for tensors with an undetermined number of indices

$$T_{\mu_1 \cdots \mu_p} \in [0,1]$$

where $\text{rank}(T)=p$